# Storm Netty Transport via API

Tags: java, apache-storm

I currently have a Storm cluster running across four Unix machines. If I understand correctly, Storm will use ZeroMQ by default.

Early performance metrics show that my cluster is slower than expected (specifically when emitting tuples from Spouts to Bolts). With this in mind I would like to switch over to Netty instead of ZMQ to see if there is a noticeable difference.

I know I can set this in the storm.yaml but my question is whether it can be done through the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like you can.  Only Configs prefixed with "topology" can be set thru the API at the topology level.  On another note, if you use the apache release netty is the default transport and ZeroMQ will probably be deprecated in future releases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - just taken a look at the apache release as you mentioned and upgraded my one (I can see now that netty is enabled by default).